WPF Update VievModel bound ListBox from CodeBehind
I'm brand new to WPF/MVVM and getting two ListBox wiht two buttons, one to copy selected elements from left listbox to the right one, and back with the second button.
At startup the left ListBox is correctly populated with data from datastore, when I select some elements and press the btn_add_symbol_Click button the AddSelectedSymbol method is executed as expected, OnPropertyChanged also, and the getter of WidgetSymbolsSelected (I suppose from the right ListBox) is called, returning the right updated CurrentWidget.Symbols. The problem is that the right ListBox, lst_SelectedSymbols, is always empty. What's going on? Thanks.
XAML:
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableSymbols}" SelectionMode="Multiple" Name="lst_AvailableSymbols" />  
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding WidgetSymbolsSelected}" SelectionMode="Multiple" Name="lst_SelectedSymbols"/>

VM:
public IEnumerable<string> AvailableSymbols
{
    get { return DataManager.AvailableSymbols; }
}

public IEnumerable<string> WidgetSymbolsSelected
{
    get { return CurrentWidget.Symbols; }
}

public void AddSelectedSymbol(string symbol)
{
    if (!CurrentWidget.Symbols.Contains(symbol)) {
        CurrentWidget.Symbols.Add(symbol);
        OnPropertyChanged("WidgetSymbolsSelected");
    }
}

CodeBehind:
private void btn_add_symbol_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var ViewModel = (WidgetEditorViewModel)this.DataContext;
    foreach (var Item in lst_AvailableSymbols.SelectedItems)
    {
        ViewModel.AddSelectedSymbol(Item.ToString());
    }
}


Have a look at changing the IEnumerable to ObservableCollection

Thanks @Hayden, it works! I need to better study the relations between ObservableCollections and OnPropertyChanged("")... Coming from WinForms... lot of mysterious concepts here :)

I notice you've got a comment on your post which solves this, but I thought I'd add a little bit of context in case it helps anyone understand why this fixes the problem.
WPF uses the PropertyChanged event (of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface) to know when to re-fetch the property, by calling the get method for it. If the reference value from the get hasn't changed, WPF is not going to re-populate all of the items from the collection.
While you've modified the underlying collection, the actual object reference to the collection itself hasn't changed, so WPF's PropertyChanged event won't re-enumerate the values of the collection (if you had, instead replaced the collection entirely with a new list object, that would be a different story).
ObservableCollection<T> has done you the favor of implementing INotifyCollectionChanged which raises an event when the collection elements change, informing WPF that it needs to adjust the UI to account for new items in the collection.  This also means you do not need to raise the property changed event yourself (for this use case), since it's not doing anything.

Thanks @AceGambit, this really made me understand what goes on under the hood.

Example of implementation, without preserving the primary sorting
namespace Core2024.SO.DPZ.question79152344
{
    public class SomeTextItem
    {
        private string _title = string.Empty;
        private string _text = string.Empty;
        private string _description = string.Empty;

        public string Title { get => _title; set => _title = value ?? string.Empty; }
        public string Text { get => _text; set => _text = value ?? string.Empty; }
        public string Description { get => _description; set => _description = value ?? string.Empty; }
    }
}

using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Simplified; // This is the space with my implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged and ICommand interfaces. You can use your own implementations instead.

namespace Core2024.SO.DPZ.question79152344
{
    public class SomeTextViewModel
    {
        private const string data = "I'm brand new to WPF/MVVM and getting two ListBox wiht two buttons, one to copy selected elements from left listbox to the right one, and back with the second button.";
        private static IEnumerable<SomeTextItem> GetItems()
        {
            string[] split = data.Split();
            for (int i = 2; i < split.Length; i += 3)
            {
                yield return new SomeTextItem()
                {
                    Title = split[i - 2],
                    Text = split[i - 1],
                    Description = split[i]
                };
            }
        }
        public SomeTextViewModel()
        {
            AvailableSymbols = new ObservableCollection<SomeTextItem>(GetItems());
            WidgetSymbolsSelected = new();
            SelectTextItem = new RelayCommand<SomeTextItem>
            (
                item => { AvailableSymbols.Remove(item); WidgetSymbolsSelected.Add(item); },
                item => AvailableSymbols.Contains(item)
            );
            UnselectTextItem = new RelayCommand<SomeTextItem>
            (
                item => { WidgetSymbolsSelected.Remove(item); AvailableSymbols.Add(item); },
                item => WidgetSymbolsSelected.Contains(item)
            );
        }

        public ObservableCollection<SomeTextItem> AvailableSymbols { get; }
        public ObservableCollection<SomeTextItem> WidgetSymbolsSelected { get; }

        public RelayCommand SelectTextItem { get; }
        public RelayCommand UnselectTextItem { get; }
    }
}

<Window x:Class="Core2024.SO.DPZ.question79152344.WidgetSymbolsSelectedWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2024.SO.DPZ.question79152344"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="WidgetSymbolsSelectedWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        DataContext="{DynamicResource vm}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:SomeTextViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeTextItem}">
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding Title}"/><Run Text=";"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Text}"/><Run Text=";"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Description}"/><Run Text=";"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <UniformGrid Columns="3">
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableSymbols}"/>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Content="-&gt;" Margin="10" Padding="15 5"
                    Command="{Binding SelectTextItem, Mode=OneWay}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listBox}"/>
            <Button Content="&lt;-" Margin="10" Padding="15 5"
                    Command="{Binding UnselectTextItem, Mode=OneWay}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listBox1}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding WidgetSymbolsSelected}"/>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>

Example of implementation with preservation of primary sorting
using Simplified;

namespace Core2024.SO.DPZ.question79152344
{
    public class SelectableSomeTextItem : BaseInpc
    {
        private string _title = string.Empty;
        private string _text = string.Empty;
        private string _description = string.Empty;
        private bool _isSelected;

        public string Title { get => _title; set => _title = value ?? string.Empty; }
        public string Text { get => _text; set => _text = value ?? string.Empty; }
        public string Description { get => _description; set => _description = value ?? string.Empty; }

        public bool IsSelected { get => _isSelected; set => Set(ref _isSelected, value); }
    }

}

using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Simplified; // This is the space with my implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged and ICommand interfaces. You can use your own implementations instead.

namespace Core2024.SO.DPZ.question79152344
{
    public class SelectableSomeTextViewModel
    {
        private const string data = "I'm brand new to WPF/MVVM and getting two ListBox wiht two buttons, one to copy selected elements from left listbox to the right one, and back with the second button.";
        private static IEnumerable<SelectableSomeTextItem> GetItems()
        {
            string[] split = data.Split();
            for (int i = 2; i < split.Length; i += 3)
            {
                yield return new SelectableSomeTextItem()
                {
                    Title = split[i - 2],
                    Text = split[i - 1],
                    Description = split[i]
                };
            }
        }
        public SelectableSomeTextViewModel()
        {
            AvailableSymbols = new ObservableCollection<SelectableSomeTextItem>(GetItems());
            SelectTextItem = new RelayCommand<SelectableSomeTextItem>
            (
                item => item.IsSelected = true,
                item => AvailableSymbols.Contains(item) && !item.IsSelected
            );
            UnselectTextItem = new RelayCommand<SelectableSomeTextItem>
            (
                item => item.IsSelected = false,
                item => AvailableSymbols.Contains(item) && item.IsSelected
            );
        }

        public ObservableCollection<SelectableSomeTextItem> AvailableSymbols { get; }

        public RelayCommand SelectTextItem { get; }
        public RelayCommand UnselectTextItem { get; }
    }
}

<Window x:Class="Core2024.SO.DPZ.question79152344.SelectableWidgetSymbolsSelectedWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2024.SO.DPZ.question79152344" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=netstandard"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="SelectableWidgetSymbolsSelectedWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        DataContext="{DynamicResource vm}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:SelectableSomeTextViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SelectableSomeTextItem}">
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding Title}"/><Run Text=";"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Text}"/><Run Text=";"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Description}"/><Run Text=";"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="items.Unselected"
                              Source="{Binding AvailableSymbols}"
                              IsLiveFilteringRequested="True"
                              Filter="OnUnselectedFilter">
            <CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
                <sys:String>IsSelected</sys:String>
            </CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
        </CollectionViewSource>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="items.Selected"
                              Source="{Binding AvailableSymbols}"
                              IsLiveFilteringRequested="True"
                              Filter="OnSelectedFilter">
            <CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
                <sys:String>IsSelected</sys:String>
            </CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>
    <UniformGrid Columns="3">
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource items.Unselected}}"/>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Content="-&gt;" Margin="10" Padding="15 5"
                    Command="{Binding SelectTextItem, Mode=OneWay}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listBox}"/>
            <Button Content="&lt;-" Margin="10" Padding="15 5"
                    Command="{Binding UnselectTextItem, Mode=OneWay}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listBox1}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox1"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource items.Selected}}"/>
    </UniformGrid>
    <x:Code>
        <![CDATA[
        private void OnUnselectedFilter(object sender, System.Windows.Data.FilterEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Accepted = !((SelectableSomeTextItem)e.Item).IsSelected;
        }

        private void OnSelectedFilter(object sender, System.Windows.Data.FilterEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Accepted = ((SelectableSomeTextItem)e.Item).IsSelected;
        }
        ]]>
    </x:Code>
</Window>

You can take my implementations of base classes from here: An example of my implementation of base classes: BaseInpc, RelayCommand, RelayCommandAsync, RelayCommand<T>, RelayCommandAsync<T>.

Thanks @EldHasp, it works great and introduces some in-depth concepts that I need to explore further in my little experience.
